# In Python, how to use a file for writing bytes in it and reading as text

Tags: python, filehandler

I would like to save bytes to a file and then read that file as a text. Can I do it with one `with`? What should I use, `wb`, `r` or `wbr`?

```
myBytesVar = b'line1\nline2'
with open('myFile.txt', 'wb') as fw:
    fw.write(myBytesVar)

with open('myFile.txt', 'r') as fr:
    myVar = fr.read()
    print(myVar)
```

Comment: Why can't you just write `myBytesVar` to the file and re-use it with `myVar = myBytesVar.decode('utf-8')`?

Comment: Thanks. Do I need utf8 if I have coding:utf-8 at the beginning of a script?

Comment: By "with one `with`" do you mean that something like this is acceptable: `with open("myFile.txt", "wb") as outFile, open("myFile.txt", "r") as inFile:`? This should work, although it's just syntactic sugar for a double `with`.

Comment: @HrvojeT: The encoding that your Python script file itself uses and the encoding your `myFile.txt` uses are two completely different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to re-read the file if you already have its contents stored in `myBytesVar`:

```
myBytesVar = b'line1\nline2'

with open('myFile.txt', 'wb') as fw:
    fw.write(myBytesVar)

myVar = myBytesVar.decode('utf-8')
```

The encoding Python assumes when reading files as text without an explicit encoding is [platform-dependent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), so I'm just assuming UTF-8 will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with one "with": When you write it "wb" is good. 
when you read the file try it

```
myvar = open('MyVar.txt', 'r').read()
print(myvar)
```

Comment: Do I have to close the file then?

Comment: No, what' it need. you already write into file "Myfile.txt" when you see your file "Myfile.txt" it contains line1line2

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information on what mode we should use :

> The default mode is 'r' (open for reading text, synonym of 'rt'). For
>   binary read-write access, the mode 'w+b' opens and truncates the file
>   to 0 bytes. 'r+b' opens the file without truncation.

Read more here.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open